# Identity server 4 and api application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4

I am now working a application . First I create a solution , inside this solution create api , identity server 4 app and web application . My question is user table can share both api and identity server  4 . cause mobile apps register user using api application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Web API application is protected by Identity Server , so you are facing one of the below two scenarios :

1. User login in and authenticated in your mobile application which protected by Identity server4 ,  you can use Authorization Code or Hybrid Flow(You can use [AppAuth](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS/blob/master/Examples/README-IdentityServer.md) for mobile) for authentication and acquiring access token which could be used to access your protected web api .
2. [Protecting the API using Client Credentials](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html) , so your mobile application will request an access token at IdentityServer and use it to gain access to the API.

Your web api application and Identity Server4 shares the same database , so each of the application can manage the users .